# How to do INSERT ... ON DUPLUCATE KEY UPDATE with old and new rows?

Tags: mysql, insert-update

I'd like to add rows to my relationship table, where there will be old rows updated and new rows added. Here is my query (ID is the only key):

```
INSERT INTO table_rel (ID, player, team, status) VALUES (1,1,1,0), (2,3,1,1) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status=VALUES(status);
```

What do I put in place of ID in rows that are supposed to be created? eg. `(false,2,1,1)`

Comment: for auto_incs just don't have placeholders. skip em

Comment: ... or supply a NULL value, either using a NULL keyword, or an expression that evaluates to NULL. See my answer for a demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is for an AUTO_INCREMENT column, you can supply a `NULL` value.
Easiest way to do that is the keyword NULL

```
 INSERT INTO table_rel (ID, player, team, status) VALUES
  (1,1,1,0)
 ,(2,3,1,1)
 ,(NULL,6,1,0)
   ^^^^
```

There's a lot of other expressions you can use to return a NULL value.

---

Demonstration supplying NULL keyword for AUTO_INCREMENT column, along with other rows that have a non-NULL value supplied:

```
CREATE TABLE foo 
( id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
, mi VARCHAR(5)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
;

INSERT INTO foo (id, mi) VALUES
 (1,'1')
,(NULL,'too')
;
-- 2 row(s) affected 

INSERT INTO foo (id, mi) VALUES 
 (1,'one')
,(NULL,'three')
,(2,'two')
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE mi = VALUES(mi)
;
-- 5 row(s) affected 

SELECT * FROM foo
;
--  id  mi
-- ---  ------
--   1  one
--   2  two
--   3  three
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't. With:

```
INSERT INTO table_rel (ID, player, team, status) ...
```

you are committing to provide ALL the listed values. Then with

```
... VALUES (1,1,1,0), (2,3,1,1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE status=VALUES(status);
```

you are providing the actual values, `ID` included (even for new entries). In this case if there isn't any `ID=1` or `ID=2` the entry will be created, otherwise for duplicate keys `value` will be overwritten.

Another solution if you don't want to specify the key for new entries then you have to use a different statement (note the missing column):

```
INSERT INTO table_rel (player, team, status) VALUES (1,1,0), (3,1,1)
```

provided that `table_rel` has the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option on `ID` (just in case: `ALTER TABLE table_rel MODIFY ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;`).

**UPDATE:**
Relying on `AUTO_INCREMENT` you can provide a `NULL` key and let the engine generate a new key for you. See [spencer7593's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39907090/1029516) for a more complete description.

Comment: So do I omit the ID altogether? as in `(,1,1,0)` or do I provide the values with one column missing `(1,1,0)` and SQL will know that it's the ID? The table does have autoincrement and I wanted to hit 2 birds with one stone

Comment: as pointed out by @spencer7593 you should use `(NULL,1, 1,0)`, otherwise use the second statement with `(1,1,0)`. `(,1,1,0)` is not a valid syntax.